# Есть выражение "водить беседы" - что оно значит?

Tags: фразеология, значение-слов

*Самому с собой водить беседы полезно.*

Comment: Если это вопрос, поставьте знак вопроса.

Comment: Водить беседы - известное, но устаревшее выражение.

Comment: как-то с ним покрасивше звучит...

Answer (score 1):

В старых текстах встречается:

1) Он расспрашивал обо всем своего соседа, старого кучера, который охотно **водил беседы с Чайкиным,** видимо возбудившим к себе участие. [К. М. Станюкович. Похождения одного матроса (1900)]

2) [По одной подруге реквием (Райнер Мария Рильке, перевод Б. Пастернака)](http://omiliya.org/article/po-odnoy-podruge-rekviem-rayner-mariya-rilke)

Я похожу по рекам, расспрошу
о старине, **пойду водить беседы**
с хозяйками у притолок дверных
и перейму, как те детей сзывают.

Comment: но сейчас ведь уместно в употреблении?

Comment: Трудно сказать,  надо поискать в современных текстах, но в любом случае  частотность употребления невысокая.

Answer (score 0):

Песня из к/ф "Анискин и Фантомас"

.

Месяц свои блестки

По лугам рассыпал.

Стройные березки,

Стройные березки

Что-то шепчут липам.

.

Припев:

.

Травы, травы, травы не успели

От росы серебряной согнуться.

И такие нежные напевы, ах,

Почему-то прямо в сердце льются.

Лунною тропою

На свиданье еду,

**Тихо сам с собою,**

**Тихо сам с собою**

**Я веду беседу.**

.

припев

.

К милой подойду я,

Глаз поднять не смея,
И от поцелуя,

И от поцелуя

Словно захмелею.

.

Слова И. Юшина